# ¿Cuál es el código de Regex?

Tags: python, regex, regular

Necesito sacar de este texto (#11: 0.00+255.00)(#12: 0.00+70.00) con un código de regex solo los números que no son 0 y no se encuentran detrás del corchete #. Es decir, en este caso necesitaría sacar 255 y 70.
Por ahora he podido con esta fórmula `[1-9(?=1-9)]{1,3}[^\W]` los números 11,255,12 y 70, pero no necesito ni el 11 ni el 12.

En defecto también me valdría obtener todo lo que no quiero, es decir, esos 0 y los signos de puntuación para usar un remove y quitar eso y quedarme con lo demás.

¿Podrían ayudarme con esto por favor?

Espero vuestras respuestas, muchas gracias!

Comment: debería de colocar un ejemplo de lo que has intentado hacer

Answer (score 2):

Mirando los datos se deduce que los valores de interés empiezan con "+" y contienen un punto decimal.

El patrón para tal caso es:

```
\+(\d+\.\d+)
```

#### Demo

```
import re

patron = re.compile(r"\+(\d+\.\d+)")

texto = "(#11: 0.00+255.00)(#12: 0.00+70.00)"
m = patron.findall(texto)
print(m)
```

produce una lista de cadenas numéricas, que luego puedes convertir a una lista de `float` si te apetece.:

```
['255.00', '70.00']

Process finished with exit code 0
```